# javascript - populate input[type=file] with newly downloaded image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to populate the downloaded image straight into `<input type="file">` with `javascript`?

I have a website that allow user to change `avatar` image and `background` image with 2 `<input type="file">` separately. After that the `avatar` and `background` will be display nicely on the page.

However, if UserA already have an `avatar` and `background` uploaded, and the next round he only want to change only `background`, he will click on the `background` and change the `background`. and leave the `avatar` button untouched. If this is the case, I need to put the `avatar` image( already downloaded from server) straight into `<input type="file">` then execute the `uploadImage` function:

```
function uploadImage(){
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('Avatar',$('#avatar')[0].files[0]);
        formData.append('Background',$('#background')[0].files[0]);

        $.ajax({
        url: uploadurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        headers:{
                Authorization : getPref('auth_token')
            },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            myApp.alert("Upload done!",null);
        },
          error:function(xhr, status)
          {
            console.log(status);
            myApp.alert("Please try again later.",'Connection fail!',null);
          }
        });
}
```

But I don't know how to get the image file from the download url.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I don't think Javascript is allowed to pre-fill a `file` input. For security reasons, the user has to select it explicitly, to prevent web sites from forcing unwanted uploads.

Comment: Why don't you just allow the avatar input to be left empty? If the user already has an avatar, and the field is empty, leave it alone on the server.

Comment: You absolutely don't need to fill the file input, you can just send it in the formData as a Blob directly (but I wonder why you even need to do this, add an id, and only upload the required image, do the merging server-side)

Comment: in that case, is there a way for me to get the image file that I already downloaded and I can straight `append()` it for upload process?

Comment: yes `xhr.open('yourfile.jpg') xhr.responseType = 'blob' xhr.onload = function(){yourFile = this.response;};` or even `fetch('yourFile.jpg')
.then(function(response) {
  return response.blob();
}).then(function(yourBlob) {...`

Comment: @Kaiido can you put it into proper answer? So that I can accept it.

Comment: may be later, don't have time to write a proper answer now...